# Can I still get Eclipse without an installer?

Tags: java, eclipse

When Eclipse announced the IDE now uses an installer instead of a download-and-unzip binary, I was less than happy. Not requiring an installation was to me one of the greatest benefits of Eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Is there a way to get the Eclipse Mars binary still without an installation?

Comment: You can download zip file from following link

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/marsr

Comment: It's actually just 50 pixels under the download button and they even mention it in the same announcement: ["For those not into installers, we still have the packages and zip files available on our download pages."](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/installer-instructions.php).  A little effort is the minimal requerement for a SO question. Check out [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay thanks, I have no idea why I overlooked this even though I spent twenty minutes googling and searching for it.

Comment: I forgive you, I blame booze.

Comment: Haha or just doing this at the end of the workday. I'll close the question.

Comment: Updated link for newcomers: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still find zip in this [page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) under `Package Solutions`

Comment: direct link now:  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the direct link:
[Direct Link To Eclipse Oxygen 2022-09](https://archive.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/3a/eclipse-java-oxygen-3a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

And if you want to browse the releases, use navigate here:
[Releases](https://archive.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/)

[image: Screenshot with wget]